# Error: type mismatch flatMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark programming and scala and i am not able to understand the difference between map and flatMap.
I tried below code as i was expecting both to work but got error.

```
scala> val b = List("1","2", "4", "5")
b: List[String] = List(1, 2, 4, 5)

scala> b.map(x => (x,1))
res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((1,1), (2,1), (4,1), (5,1))

scala> b.flatMap(x => (x,1))
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int)
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              b.flatMap(x => (x,1))
```

As per my understanding flatmap make Rdd in to collection for String/Int Rdd.
I was thinking that in this case both should work without any error.Please let me know where i am making the mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at how the signatures defined these methods:

```
def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U]
```

`map` takes a function from type `T` to type `U` and returns an `RDD[U]`.

On the other hand, `flatMap`:

```
def flatMap[U: ClassTag](f: T => TraversableOnce[U]): RDD[U]
```

Expects a function taking type `T` to a `TraversableOnce[U]`, which is a trait `Tuple2` doesn't implement, and returns an `RDD[U]`. Generally, you use `flatMap` when you want to flatten a collection of collections, i.e. if you had an `RDD[List[List[Int]]` and you want to produce a `RDD[List[Int]]` you can flatMap it using `identity`.

Comment: Thank you @YuvalItzchakov for the help if i understand it correct when i used flatmap on list(1,2,4 ..) it was just a collection not collection of collection so it showed the error

Comment: @Anaadih Yes, that's correct. The projection expects a `TraversableOnce[U]`, which is a collection type.

Answer (score 3):

Map operation return type is **U**  where as flatMap return type is **TraversableOnce[U]**(means collections)

```
val b = List("1", "2", "4", "5")
val mapRDD = b.map { input => (input, 1) }
mapRDD.foreach(f => println(f._1 + "  " + f._2))

val flatmapRDD = b.flatMap { input => List((input, 1)) }
flatmapRDD.foreach(f => println(f._1 + "  " + f._2))
```

Comment: Simple and clear. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

**map(func)**   Return a new distributed dataset formed by passing each element of the source through a function func.

**flatMap(func)**   Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0 or more output items (so func should return a Seq rather than a single item).

The following example might be helpful.

```
        scala> val b = List("1", "2", "4", "5")
        b: List[String] = List(1, 2, 4, 5)

        scala> b.map(x=>Set(x,1))
        res69: List[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any]] =     
        List(Set(1, 1), Set(2, 1), Set(4, 1), Set(5, 1))

        scala> b.flatMap(x=>Set(x,1))
        res70: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1)

        scala> b.flatMap(x=>List(x,1))
        res71: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1)

        scala> b.flatMap(x=>List(x+1))
        res75: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = List(11, 21, 41, 51) // concat




        scala> val x = sc.parallelize(List("aa bb cc dd",  "ee ff gg hh"), 2)

        scala> val y = x.map(x => x.split(" ")) // split(" ") returns an array of words
        scala> y.collect
        res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(aa, bb, cc, dd), Array(ee, ff, gg, hh))

        scala> val y = x.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
        scala> y.collect
        res1: Array[String] = Array(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh)
```

Answer (score 0):

map does a 1-to-1 transformation, while flatMap converts a list of lists to a single list:

```
scala> val b = List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6), List(7,8,90))
b: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 90))

scala> b.map(x => (x,1))
res1: List[(List[Int], Int)] = List((List(1, 2, 3),1), (List(4, 5, 6),1), (List(7, 8, 90),1))

scala> b.flatMap(x => x)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 90)
```

Also, flatMap is useful for filtering out `None` values if you have a list of `Option`s:

```
scala> val c = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3), Some(4), None)
c: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3), Some(4), None)

scala> c.flatMap(x => x)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you @anthonybell for information but in my case of map and flatMap i have used a single list but i am still getting error in this.

Comment: `flatMap` expects each 'item' in your list to also be a list.  If you wrote `b.flatMap(x => List((x,1)))` instead it would work the same as `map`.